# Prevent cursor from moving when scrolling in Microsoft Word (Office 365)

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, scrolling

Sometimes I like to scroll ahead in a document and see what's going on, then use the arrow keys to give a nudge back to where I was.  I recently upgraded to the latest version of Office 365, after sticking to Office 2011 for Mac for a long time, and got the very unpleasant surprise that it "helpfully" moves the cursor along so it's always on screen when scrolling, making it very hard for me to jump back to where I was.

Is there a way to disable this behavior?

Comment: Try in menu File > Options -> Advanced to uncheck "Use Smart Cursoring".

Comment: @harrymc That's definitely the right feature by the look of it, however it seems MS doesn't lay things out the same way on a Mac; there's no "Options" item on the File menu; have to go to the main application menu to get the "Preferences" panel, which doesn't appear to organize things the way the PC version does.

Comment: Not on the Mac, I don't know where this option is hidden. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

By design or error, the Mac Office team does not appear to have implemented the feature where you could turn Smart Cursoring off.

Send them direct feedback by using the Smiley control, which is a pull-down menu button on the far right end of the ribbon.

Comment: Came to the same conclusion.  Thanks for the reminder to come and share that, however!